# repeating row of a column in a data frame n as the same length of another column

Tags: r

suppose I have these data:

```
year<- c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002)
H<- c(1.5,2.5,3,4.7,5.7,6.5,3.2,2.1,1.9)
a<- c(11:19)
b<- c(21:29)

df<- data_frame(year,H,a,b)
df
# A tibble: 9 × 4
   year     H     a     b
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1  2000   1.5    11    21
2  2000   2.5    12    22
3  2000   3      13    23
4  2001   4.7    14    24
5  2001   5.7    15    25
6  2001   6.5    16    26
7  2002   3.2    17    27
8  2002   2.1    18    28
9  2002   1.9    19    29
```

in R how can I repeat `H` for each year in such a way that for each year the group of data in `a` and `b` be repeated.
my expected output is like this:

```
    year     H     a     b
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2000   1.5    11    21
 2  2000   1.5    12    22
 3  2000   1.5    13    23
 4  2000   2.5    11    21
 5  2000   2.5    12    22
 6  2000   2.5    13    23
 7  2000   3      11    21
 8  2000   3      12    22
 9  2000   3      13    23
10  2001   4.7    14    24
11  2001   4.7    15    25
12  2001   4.7    16    26
13  2001   5.7    14    24
14  2001   5.7    15    25
15  2001   5.7    16    26
16  2001   6.5    14    24
17  2001   6.5    15    25
18  2001   6.5    16    26
19  2002   3.2    17    27
20  2002   3.2    18    28
21  2002   3.2    19    29
22  2002   2.1    17    27
23  2002   2.1    18    28
24  2002   2.1    19    29
25  2002   1.9    17    27
26  2002   1.9    18    28
27  2002   1.9    19    29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::expand_grid()` which accepts data frames.  In this case, group by year, and then iterate over the groups with `group_modify()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  group_modify(~ expand_grid(.x[1], .x[-1]))

# A tibble: 27 x 4
# Groups:   year [3]
    year     H     a     b
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
 1  2000   1.5    11    21
 2  2000   1.5    12    22
 3  2000   1.5    13    23
 4  2000   2.5    11    21
 5  2000   2.5    12    22
 6  2000   2.5    13    23
 7  2000   3      11    21
 8  2000   3      12    22
 9  2000   3      13    23
10  2001   4.7    14    24
# ... with 17 more rows
```

Or same idea without using `group_modify()` which is an experimental function:

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  split(~ year) %>%
  map_df(~ expand_grid(.x[1:2], .x[3:4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

year<- c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002)
H<- c(1.5,2.5,3,4.7,5.7,6.5,3.2,2.1,1.9)
a<- c(11:19)
b<- c(21:29)

df<- data.frame(year,H,a,b)

df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(H = rep(H, each = n()), across(-1, ~ rep(.x, n())), .groups = "drop")

#> # A tibble: 27 × 4
#>     year     H     a     b
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#>  1  2000   1.5    11    21
#>  2  2000   1.5    12    22
#>  3  2000   1.5    13    23
#>  4  2000   2.5    11    21
#>  5  2000   2.5    12    22
#>  6  2000   2.5    13    23
#>  7  2000   3      11    21
#>  8  2000   3      12    22
#>  9  2000   3      13    23
#> 10  2001   4.7    14    24
#> # … with 17 more rows
```